# Climbing up the slope task, using while loop to solve in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a beginner in Python. I am getting stuck at a while-loop question:

"Herbert the Heffalump is trying to climb up a scree slope. He finds that the best approach is to rush up the slope until he's exhausted, then pause to get his breath back. However, while he pauses each time, the slope settles underneath him, carrying him back down part of the slope he just climbed.

Write a function `num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding)` that calculates how many rushes it takes Herbert to climb up a slope of height `slope_height` metres, given that each rush gains him `rush_height_gain` metres before he slides back `back_sliding` metres during the pause before the next rush. The final rush will still be counted as 1 rush, even though it may be of shorter duration than the previous rushes.

In addition to the while loop condition, you will also need to check after each rush whether Herbert has reached the top of the slope. Of course he only slides backwards if he isn't at the top of the slope!"

And my solution is:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    """Calculates the number of rushes needed for Herbert the Heffalump to climb the slope."""
    
    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0

    while current_height < slope_height:        # If not reach the top yet
        current_height = current_height + rush_height_gain   
        rushes += 1                             # Add 1 to the number of rushes
        if current_height >= slope_height:      # If the last rush takes him to the top, 
            rushes += 0                         # then no sliding back
                                           # If not reach the top yet,
        else:
            current_height = current_height + rush_height_gain - back_sliding   # slide back
            rushes += 1

    return rushes
```

The test cases are:

```
ans = num_rushes(10, 10, 9)
print(ans)  ==> SHOULD PRINT 1

ans = num_rushes(100, 10, 0)
print(ans)  ==> SHOULD PRINT 10

ans = num_rushes(15, 10, 5)
print(ans)  ==> SHOULD PRINT 2

ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7) 
print(ans)  ==> SHOULD PRINT 12
```

My function returns the correct outputs for the first 3 test cases.
In the last test case (100, 15, 7), it prints 9 instead of 12.

Can anyone please spot something wrong in the logic of my codes? I've tried for several hours but it looks all good to me.

Comment: I suggest you also step though the code with a debugger - should be pretty easy to spot if it doing the right thing on each iteration as you inspect the changes in your variables (`num_rushes` and `current_height`) in each loop - what it starts out at and what it ends up at for each iteration.

Comment: debugging is a basic skill you need to learn. step through your code carefully, use print statements to verify it's doing what you think...

Comment: Actually, you don't need any loops to solve this problem. Just work out an equation that binds together three parameters and the unknown N (= number of steps), solve it for N and obtain the formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    one_rush = rush_height_gain - back_sliding
    return 1 + math.ceil((slope_height - rush_height_gain) / one_rush)

>[num_rushes(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip([10, 100, 15, 100], [10, 10, 10, 15], [9, 0, 5, 7])]
[1, 10, 2, 12]
```

The altitude at `(slope_height - rush_height_gain)` is guaranteed to reach the top `slope_height` on the next rush.

So the answer is `1` (the last rush), more the number of rushes necessary to reach `(slope_height - rush_height_gain)`, which is `((slope_height - rush_height_gain) / one_rush)`.

The last value is rounded up with `math.ceil()`, because of course, is not possible to do a fraction of a rush.

Comment: While your code is useful you should include an explanation of _why_ is it useful, and _what_ you have done differently from the code in the question. As it says in the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help page "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the additional `rushes += 1` in the else clause, which results in counting each rush twice. You can just use `if current_height < slope_height` instead of the whole `if-else` fiasco:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    """Calculates the number of rushes needed for Herbert the Heffalump to climb the slope."""
    
    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0

    while current_height < slope_height:        
        current_height = current_height + rush_height_gain    
        rushes += 1                           
        
        # Check if Herbert hasn't reached the top
        # Herbert slides back if not at the top
        if current_height < slope_height:       
            current_height -= back_sliding      

    return rushes

ans = num_rushes(10, 10, 9)
print(ans)  # Should print 1

ans = num_rushes(100, 10, 0)
print(ans)  # Should print 10

ans = num_rushes(15, 10, 5)
print(ans)  # Should print 2

ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7) 
print(ans)  # Should print 12
```

Output:

```
1
10
2
12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the error.